# How to restart a php while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I have 5 rows of data in mysql database table. I want to display those five rows randomly so I used ORDER BY rand() function but the problem is I want to stop the while loop after 2 rows have been fetched and add some html there and again continue from row 3. Is this possible?

Here's the code I tried but problem is with this code I get 2 rows repeated 90% of times...

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 2";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

//display till 2 rows

?>

<!-- add some html block -->

<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rand()";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

mysqli_data_seek($result,2);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

//display from row 3 now till last row

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it within a single while loop itself (one query). Use a counter, and when it hits 2, you insert a one time block of html, then the while continues onward.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rand()";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$r = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    // your row display code here above the next block

    if (++$r == 2) {
        // now when r is 2, inject that one-time html block
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use one query and one loop?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rand()";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($i == 2) {
    ?>
    <!-- add some html block -->
    <?php
    }
    //display row data
    $i++;
}
```

You can add other `if` statements to display rows differently if they are `< 3` or `> 2` etc.